# Creating cleaner menus in BASH that don't simply scroll up screen

Tags: linux, bash

I have been creating a menus in bash using sepect and read command to test network connections.

please enter address
please select bandwidth
please select protocol

etc

When i run this it simple scrolls the out put up the screen and for a select choise if the user hits the worng key it just types it all out again as below.

Is there any way to have it to clear the screen between each question rather than scroll it simply over writes? This selection of questions is going to be quite long and i would like to keep the terminal screen as clean as possible.

here is a snipit of the code

```
echo "Welcome to iperf3 testing script"
echo "Before running this script insure iperf 3 and MRT are insalled on this client"
echo "Before running this script insure the server side is running using the command"
echo "iperf3 -s -i 10"

## allow user to exit script if they are not ready to run it
echo "Do you wish to continue"
select con in Yes No
do

case $con in
"No")
exit
;;
"Yes")
break
;;
esac
done
```

and this gives the following outputbelow, What i would like to be able to do is

1. If the user enters an invalid choice it clears the input and rewrites it (possible with a message saying the need to chose a valid choice)
2. Once the first question is answered it clears the screen and displays the next one.

I have looked up some simple "clear screen" commands but then this means jumping around the code. I havent found and standard way to do this but i have seen script in the past that do do it.

If any one has any guidence on creating neat menues in Bash would be greatful to hear about them

Welcome to iperf3 testing script
Before running this script insure iperf 3 and MRT are insalled on this client
Before running this script insure the server side is running using the command
iperf3 -s -i 10
Do you wish to continue
1) Yes
2) No
#? 4
#? 4
#? 4
#? 3
#? 1
Please Enter the Iperf3 Server IP: 2.2.2.2
Please  Select  UDP or TCP to test with
1) TCP
2) UDP
#? 3
#? 3
#? 2
Please Select Test duration per test in seconds:
1) 10
2) 30
3) 60
4) 120
5) 300

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you looking for here, other than how to clear the screen, or how to loop until input is valid? (We have questions on both of those topics already answered; if you're having trouble _combining_ those answers, can you be more specific  about which existing answers you've considered and found unworkable, and if you found them unworkable, why that is?)

Comment: ...with respect to "neat menus", that's a larger/wider topic, and often involves use of tools other than bash itself ([dialog](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/) and its many clones are a place to start). However, tool recommendations are off-topic here -- see #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Well when i searched for "clear bash menu between inputs" and variations with in stackover flow nothing came up. Hence the reson for asking the question.  The clear screen one is obvious of course but when creating a large menu structure with lots of nested menus is keeping instructions and selections on screen gets complicated. I supose what i really want is a way to keep the screen the same apart from the choices (part in the Select statment) and only refresh that part

Comment: IF that takes requiremnt out side then not some where i want to go, want to keep it all in native bash

Comment: I do not see another method than keeping the current selections in variables and reprinting the entire thing after a `clear`.  That is what I have done, it works fine.

Comment: @DevilWAH : If `clear` is not enough for you, you could use [`tput`](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html) to move the cursor around to that position where you want the next output to start - provided your TERM settings allow this. The _tput_ _man-page_ also contains some examples.

Comment: cheers Nic, that pressty much waht i am doing, just felt like a lot of code burried in nested statment and thought there would be a "cleaner" way to manage it. But sounds like not so i shall continue. Cheer for the conformation#

Comment: If you structure your code cleanly, you don't need to bury things in a deeply nested manner. That's not a question about bash-the-language, though, it's a question about writing clean, clear, and well-structured code (and as such, is generally too broad and opinion-based to be on-topic here).